# Is there a homeomorphism between the $n$-dimensional cube to the $n$-dimensional simplex that doesn't create hard corners?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-topology, conformal-geometry

Is there a homeomorphism between the $n$-dimensional cube to the $n$-dimensional simplex that doesn't create hard corners?  This is related to a similar question found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384713/looking-for-a-nonlinear-map-from-n-dimensional-cube-to-an-n-dimensional-si).  However, the mappings in response to that question create corners.  Specifically, I've been playing with schemes where

1. Set a direction to squeeze the point $x\in[0,1]^n$, $v$
2. Project $x$ into the nullspace of $v$, $y = x - \frac{v^Tx}{v^Tv}v$
3. Draw a line between $x$ and $y$, $l(\alpha) =  \alpha(y-x)+x$
4. $l(0)=x$, so we know it's in the hypercube.  Find
   $$
     \alpha_l = \arg\max\{\alpha\geq 0:l(\alpha)\in[0,1]^n\}
     $$
   $$
     \alpha_r = \arg\min\{\alpha\leq 0:l(\alpha)\in[0,1]^n\}
     $$
   Basically, how far left and right we can travel and stay inside the cube
5. Define the squeeze factor
   $$
     \alpha = \frac{\alpha_l}{\alpha_l-\alpha_r}
     $$
   Basically, how far between the leftmost and rightmost points we are along the direction $v$.
6. Determine a new leftmost and rightmost point on the simplex,
   $$
     z_l = l(\alpha_l)
     $$
   $$
     z_r = \frac{1-\sum x_i}{\sum (y_i-x_i)}
     $$
   It turns out the left most point is the same for the cube and the simplex.
7. Use the squeeze factor to determine the new mapping for $x$
   $$
     w=\alpha(z_r-z_l)+z_l
     $$

Anyway, that was a little circuitous, but it works.  It turns out if $v=(1,\dots,1)$, we get the first answer to the linked question above.  If we set $v = x$, we get the second scheme.

Alright, so what's the problem?  This mapping makes something that kind of looks like a reentrant corner on smooth areas mapped to the simplex.  For example, if we set $v=(1,\dots,1)$ and map a circle centered at $(0.5,0.5)$ of radius $0.25$ to the simplex, we go from
[image: Circle on a square]
to
[image: Circle on a simplex]
Basically, we get a heart shaped object with these hard corners.  I've tried a bunch of different schemes for choosing $v$ and I keep getting corners, which is undesirable.  I really want something that's mapped smoothly to the simplex.

Anyway, is there a smooth map from the hypercube to the simplex where where something like a circle mapped from the hypercube to the simplex won't have these corners?

---

### Edit 1

I think @Del has a good answer and here's what it looks like.  Given a rectangular grid

[image: rectangular grid]

The scheme transforms this into

[image: deformed grid]

which shows how the grid is squished to fit into the simplex.  It turns out this is smooth for the use case I described above.  We can see this with the deformed circle

[image: deformed circle]

Anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: What's a hard corner?

Comment: Yeah, I guess I don't have a great definition.  The example above with the circle kind of looks like a reentrant corner to me, but it may not be one, so I said hard corner.  Basically, the circle mapped to the simplex looks like a heart, which has two corner looking objects, the top and bottom of the heart.  I'd like a mapping that's smooth.  So, maybe, if we have a region enclosed by a $C^1$ function that the mapping onto the simplex stays in a $C^1$ region?

Comment: Try collapsing a side instead and rotating? Your procedure 'smooths off' a corner in the original square and perhaps this is the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have one $C^\infty$ in the interiors: first of all the cube I'm considering is $C=(0,1)^n$, while the simplex $S$ is the interior of the convex hull of $\{0,e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$, where $\{e_i\}$ is the standard orthonormal basis of $\mathbb R^n$. If $O$ denotes the open positive orthant then $C=O\cap \{x:\|x\|_\infty< 1\}$ and $S=\{x:\|x\|_1< 1\}$.

The diffeomorphism is $f:C\to S$ defined by
$$\left(f(x)\right)_i=x_i\prod_{i<j\leq n}(1-x_j)= x_i(1-x_n)\cdots (1-x_{i+1}).$$
For instance in $\mathbb R^3$ it's
$$ \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}\mapsto \begin{pmatrix} x'\\y'\\z'\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x(1-y)(1-z)\\y(1-z)\\z\end{pmatrix}.$$
You can check by backwards substitution that the inverse is
$$ \begin{pmatrix}x'\\y'\\z'\end{pmatrix}\mapsto \begin{pmatrix} x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{x'}{1-y'-z'}\\\frac{y'}{1-z}\\z'\end{pmatrix}$$
or in general
$$(f^{-1}(x'))_i=\frac{x'_i}{1-\sum\limits_{i<j\leq n}x'_j}.$$
It is obviously smooth. Let us check it sends $C$ to $S$ by induction on $n$. The case $n=2$:
$$x_1(1-x_2)+x_2=(1-x_2)(x_1-1)+1\leq 1$$
and assuming the result true for $n-1$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\prod_{i<j\leq n}(1-x_j)=x_n+(1-x_n)\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\prod_{i<j\leq n-1}(1-x_j)\leq x_n +(1-x_n)=1.$$
Moreover $f^{-1}$ sends $S$ to $C$:
$$\frac{x'_i}{1-\sum_{i<j\leq n}x'_j}\leq \frac{1-\sum_{j\neq i}x'_j}{1-\sum_{i<j\leq n}x'_j}\leq 1.$$

What it essentially does is collapsing some faces into other lower dimensional ones (as suggested by Pedro Tamaroff in the comments) and interpolating sort of linearly in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to the duplicate question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1896894/bijective-map-beween-the-unit-simplex-and-the-unit-hypecube/4637880#4637880).

[image]